# Query to seed many to many table

Tags: sql-server, query, many-to-many

How can I write a query to seed a many to many table. Let's say I have an Employee table, a Branch table, and I am introducing an EmployeeBranch table for the many to many relationship.

I need to insert records for every employee and branch combination into the EmployeeBranch table. So if there are 100 employees and 10 branches, I would end up with 1000 records; each employee will have 10 records for each branch.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum, please tag your DBMS (SQL Server, PostgreSQL, ...) the solution you're looking for may vary depending on which DB you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using SQL Server, You can use CROSS APPLY to return 1 Branch row for each Employee row:

```
SELECT e.ID AS EmployeeID,
  e.Name AS EmployeeName,
  b.BranchID,
  b.BranchName
FROM Employee e
CROSS APPLY (SELECT ID AS BranchID, BranchName FROM Branch) b
ORDER BY EmployeeID
```

See working [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=31e538df9b0cd4fb888b081c14309475).

For Postgres, similar query but using LEFT JOIN LATERAL instead:

```
SELECT e.ID AS EmployeeID,
  e.Name AS EmployeeName,
  b.ID AS BranchID,
  b.BranchName
FROM Employee e
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (SELECT ID, BranchName FROM Branch) b ON true
ORDER BY EmployeeID
```

Working [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7a441e4d2f4ae7e9358ac887393f8241) here.

Comment: You query won't work on other DB than SQLServer, besides you can CROSS APPLY  directly with Branch table instead of using a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

A simple cartesian product will suffice (using the same query structure as @HandyD):

```
SELECT e.ID AS EmployeeID,
  e.Name AS EmployeeName,
  b.BranchID,
  b.BranchName
FROM Employee e
JOIN Branch b
ORDER BY EmployeeID
```

A join without join condition will simply return all combinations.

Answer (score 0):

To get many to many, it’s enough to simply not specify the conditions for the relation of tables in the WHERE statement

Also, You can combine the selection and insert operation. `insert .. select ...` statements work on all database systems.

For t-sql (MSSQL), it looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeBranch (Employeeid, Branchid) 
SELECT Employee.id, Branch.id 
FROM Employee, Branch
```

If you do not want to insert duplicates in the EmployeeBranch table, and add only unique records, you can check this by adding a condition:

```
INSERT INTO EmployeeBranch (Employeeid, Branchid) 
SELECT Employee.id, Branch.id 
FROM Employee JOIN Branch 
    ON (NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * 
        FROM EmployeeBranch 
        WHERE Employeebranch.Branchid = Branch.Id 
    AND Employeebranch.Employeeid = Employee.Id) )
```